# C# Word Doc How To Make Multiple Changes Before Updating Document

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-word, vsto

I hope this easy but I can't seem to find it. I'm working with a word document object in an Outlook VSTO project to modify values that are located between hidden key values.

IE [key_start] text [key_end]

When they make selections in the drop down from the addin I change the text in the body of the email for them.

To make this work

1) I un-hide all my keys

```
       Word.Document doc = Inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
       doc.Content.Font.Hidden = 0;
```

2) Then find my keys and generate a range between them

```
        int start_pos = -1;
        int end_pos = -1;

        //SelectTextRange is a custom function to find range based on text
        ValueRange = Custom.WordDocument.SelectTextRange(doc, key_value_start);
        if (ValueRange != null) {
            start_pos = ValueRange.End;
        }

        ValueRange = Custom.WordDocument.SelectTextRange(doc, key_value_end);
        if (ValueRange != null) {
            end_pos = ValueRange.Start;
        }
```

3) Then update the text.

```
        if (start_pos > -1 && end_pos > -1) {
            ValueRange = doc.Range(start_pos, end_pos);
            ValueRange.Text = " new text goes here ";
        }
```

4) Then hide my keys again.

Everything works great but it looks a little tacky when the changes cascade through the doc as it updates. It looks as though the document updates on every command and doesn't wait until all my commands are finished. Is there a way to prevent the document from committing changes so I can make it do this all in one shot and not have the user see flickers of hidden text when this process occurs?

Comment: If you were using Word VBA, you would use the `Application.ScreenUpdating` property (setting it to `False` to disable screen updating, and then setting it back to `True` when you finish).  Is there anything similar in the objects you are using to connect to Word?  (Maybe `doc.Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?)

Comment: OMG THAT WORKS... Thankyou!!!

Comment: Post it as an answer (you know better than I the exact syntax you need to use for a c# version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YowE3K nailed it. Thank you again.

Adding this to the beginning of my changes

```
 doc.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

And then adding this to the end

```
 doc.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Did exactly what I needed. All my changes occured without the document updating and then once I set `doc.Application.ScreenUpdating = True` it draws the updated document with all my changes.